# How to close main window upon login to open another window?

Tags: pyqt5, pyqt6

I am new to PyQt and I have been trying to build a GUI where upon login, the first window should close and open a web-view in a new window. After some research and going through some similar posts, I have managed to run the code in PyQT5, but it does not work in PyQT6 even after making some modifications to the initial code.

Note: Please ignore the full imports, I'll fix that later.
The webview.py will be updated for webview later.

app.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from views.user import  getUserName
from views.webview import  webView

import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
#main application
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    #get username
    username = getUserName()

    if username.exec() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
        showWebView = webView()
        showWebView.show()
        app.exec()
```

user.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class getUserName(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(getUserName, self).__init__(parent)

        self.showMaximized()
        self.setWindowTitle("User Selection")

        #form fields
        self.user = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.user.setPlaceholderText('Enter UserID')

        #push button to start the webview
        self.buttonLogin = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Login', self)
        self.buttonLogin.clicked.connect(self.startWebView)

        #layout of the login window
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.user)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonLogin)

    #to be moved to a separate model and connected to a db to validate the userid
    def startWebView(self):
        if (self.user.text() == 'foo'):
            self.accept()
        else:
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(
                self, 'Error', 'Bad user or password')
```

webview.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class webView(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(webView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.showMaximized()
```

To make the code run using PyQT6, I

1. Updated all the imports to PyQT6
2. Updated app.py `QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted` to `QtWidgets.QDialog.accepted` as it was not recognizing "Accepted".

Are there any further changes that I need to make?

On another note - would it be a good idea to create stacked widgets instead rather than trying to close one window and open another one?

Comment: `QtWidgets.QDialog.DialogCode.Accepted`. [PyQt5 vs PyQt6](https://www.pythonguis.com/faq/pyqt5-vs-pyqt6/).

Comment: Please don't mark it solved by changing the title. Write an answer yourself if nobody else did. See [Why does Stack Overflow discourage adding "Solved" to question titles?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311829/why-does-stack-overflow-discourage-adding-solved-to-question-titles)

Comment: I have done that now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In PyQT6, "QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted" has been moved to "QtWidgets.QDialog.DialogCode.Accepted". I fixed this line and the code strated working fine using PyQT6.